# Pandas: concatenating data frames in iterations

Tags: pandas, concatenation

I want to concatenate data frames in a loop with pandas.concat. They have the same columns but different indexes and values and they are generated within the loop. In such way the output dataframe will 'grow' over iterations starting from empty data frame. For a list it will look like this:

```
a = []
for i in range(10):    
    a.append(i**2)
```

However, I found it is not advisable to make empty data frame. Is the only solution to get the first data frame before the loop and in the loop concat 2nd, 3rd, ... data frames?

Jarek

Comment: yes, you can do `if i == 0: a = your_df else: a = pd.concat([a, your_df])` inside your `for` loop. it's definitely gonna be working

Answer (score 0):

You could use `append`:

```
a = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(10):    
    <your code here>
    a = a.append(i)
```

Or `concat`:

```
a = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(10):    
    <your code here>
    a = pd.concat([a, i])
```